# Object is Equatable, but still getting Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'any Hashable & Identifiable' operands

Tags: swift

Not sure if this is a bug of some sort, but `object` is `Equatable`, but still looks like XCode sees it only as `Hashable & Identifiable`

```
struct NavigationDestination: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    
    let object: any Equatable & Hashable & Identifiable
    let context: [String:Any]
    
    var id: String {
        return self.object.id as! String
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: NavigationDestination, rhs: NavigationDestination) -> Bool {
        return lhs.object == rhs.object
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(id)
    }
        
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just because two objects both conform to Equatable doesn’t mean they can be compared to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` operator defined in `Equatable` can only compare things of the same type. It seems like you want `object` to be able to store *anything* that is `Equatable`, `Hashable` and `Identifiable`. This means that `lhs.object` could be a different type from `rhs.object`, and therefore cannot be compared with `==`.

Also note that `Hashable` *implies* `Equatable` anyway, so saying `Equatable` is redundant. And your `id` implementation seems to require that `Identifiable.ID` to be `String`.

I suggest that you wrap the `object` into an `AnyHashable`, so that different types of things *can* be compared for equality. You don't actually need `object` to be `Identifiable` - you can just assign to `id` in the initialiser:

```
let object: AnyHashable
let id: String
let context: [String:Any]

init<T>(object: T, context: [String: Any]) where T: Hashable, T: Identifiable<String> {
    self.context = context
    self.object = AnyHashable(object)
    self.id = object.id
}
```

Notice that the complicated type constraints are all moved to the initialiser signature, where you have much more freedom to write type constraints.